# Attach local ethernet scanner to remote office VPN

Tags: vpn, ethernet, remote-access, scanner

I'm testing an Ethernet scanner. I don't want to go into all the details why.  I can access my remote office VPN via workstations and servers just fine.  The scanner does not have an interface to log onto the VPN (obvious).  Is there a router that allows me to set up the VPN credentials so that when I plug the scanner in, the scanner will be on the remote office VPN so I can test it using the remote office workstations and servers?  My internet search results invariably bring up how to set up a VPN or utilize VPN passthrough, which is not what I'm looking for.